# Can I get the event that Load a WinForm

Tags: vb.net, winforms, events

I have two WinForm from the first `WinForm1` I call the other `WinForm2` using a button with the well-known `instanceWinForm2.ShowDialog`. From the Load event in the second `WinForm2` I want to know if the `WinForm2` was called by the button in the `WinForm1`, because the `WinForm2` can be called by other procedures.

Comment: You should move that logic to a constructor parameter.

Comment: Yeah my friend, it worked! Using the property like a flag. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Create a public boolean property on Form2, then call as follows:

```
Dim f as New Form2
f.CalledFromButton = True
f.Show
```

Then, check the property in the form load event of Form2, and it will be true when it was called from the button.